# Load SVG as clipPath with border - fabricjs

Tags: canvas, fabricjs, clip-path, fabricjs2

I need to delimit the canvas with an SVG. Before I had it with clipTo and it worked fine, but we have updated the version to the 2.3.4 of Fabric.js and clipTo no longer works, and recommend ClipPath.
When doing it with ClipPath it does it correctly, but the border does not paint it. We need to delimit the edges to highlight the editable zone.

My result with Fabric version 1.6:

[image]

My result with Fabric version 2.3.4 and clipPath:

[image]

As you can see, it does not paint the edges of the limits, although it does.

How can I perform this functionality with the new version of Fabric?

I have a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jrodrigo0809/43p28k6o/6/) with a circle of clipPath to test, without getting to add a border.

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

(function() {
    var clipPath = new fabric.Circle({
        radius: 100,
        top: -200,
        left: -200
    });
    var clipPath2 = new fabric.Circle({
        radius: 100,
        top: 0,
        left: 0
    });
    var clipPath3 = new fabric.Circle({
        radius: 100,
        top: 0,
        left: -200
    });
    var clipPath4 = new fabric.Circle({
        radius: 200,
        top: 15,
        left: 30,
        strokeWidth: 5,
        stroke: "red",
        fill: "#3ff4ff",
        hoverCursor: "pointer",
        opacity: 1,
        selectable: false,
        absolutePositioned: true,
        controlsAboveOverlay: true,
        hasBorders: true,
        borderDashArray: [3, 3],
        borderColor: 'red',
        strokeLineJoin: 'mitter',
        strokeMiterLimit: 3000,
        objectCaching: true,
        affectStroke: true
    });
    canvas.clipPath = clipPath4;
    //canvas.add(clipPath4);
    //var g = new fabric.Group([clipPath, clipPath2, clipPath3]);
    //g.inverted = true;
    fabric.Image.fromURL('http://fabricjs.com/assets/dragon.jpg', function(img) {
        //img.clipPath = g;
        img.scaleToWidth(125);
        img.left = 175;
        img.top = 175;
        canvas.add(img);
    });
    a tag

    canvas.setBackgroundColor("#00CCEE");
    console.log(canvas.ga tagetObjects());
})()
console.log(canvas.getObjects());
```